# Объясните как работает функция

Tags: python

```
def len_int (x): 
    len_ = 0
    while x:
        x //= 10
        len_  += 1
    return (len_)
```

Поясните как работает эта функция

Comment: Тут школьная арифметика, что конкретно непонятно?

Comment: Как это умно объяснить преподу в 2 словах  @andreymal

Comment: объяснять преподу надо не "умно", а так, как понимаешь. А то на "умное" объяснение рискуешь получить уточняющий вопрос, который сразу весь ум и покажет.

Answer (score 0):

У тебя, наверное, путаница с делением.
В Python'e есть два деления:

1. Обычное - `7 / 2 = 3.5`
2. Целочисленное - `7 // 2 = 3.`

При целочисленном делении дробная часть *отбрасывается* (не округляется)
Соответственно твоё выражение `X //= 10` делит X на 10 и отбрасывает дробную часть

Comment: а нижнее подчеркивание после len_ что значит?

Comment: @Adam Это для того, чтобы не перекрыть своей переменной с таким же именем встроенную функцию `len`. Это типичный способ этого избежать - добавить в конце названия переменной `_`.

Comment: Технически оно ничего не значит в данном случае. Это такая же переменная. Просто дописано _, чтобы избежать конфликта с названием функции len()

Answer (score 0):

Данная функция `len_int` ищет длину целочисленной переменной `x`.
Рассмотрим на примере, допустим `x = 567`

При входе в функцию объявляем переменную `len_` в которой будем хранить длину, и обнуляем её.

На следующем шаге запускаем цикл, который будет работать до тех пор, пока икс не будет равно нулю. В нашем примере х = 567

Мы делим икс на 10 `x = x // 10` т.е. 567 // 10 = 56
Увеличиваем счётчик `len_ = len_ + 1` т.е. мы посчитали цифру 7, её длина равна 1

Ещё за два шага аналогично 56 делим на 10, получаем 5 и длина 2.
5 делим на 10 получаем ноль, длина 3

В результате выполнения функции, если мы передадим значение `567`, то мы получим результат 3. Это значит, что длина числа 567 равна трём символам, что нам было и нужно

Answer (score 0):

Она возвращает длину переданного числа.
Например ты передаешь в аргумент функции **100**

```
def len_int (x):  # 100
len_ = 0
while x:  # Пока x не равно нулю
    x //= 10  # отбрасываем последний символ
    len_  += 1  # аккумулируем при каждой итерации
return (len_)
```

Цикл `while x:` работает до тех пор, пока x не станет нулем.
На каждой итерации отбрасываем последний символ и увеличиваем счетчик len_.

1. x == 100 // 10 = 10; len_ == 1
2. x == 10 // 10 = 1; len_ == 2
3. x == 1 // 10 = 0; len_ == 3

А 4й итерации уже не будет, так как x == 0 и цикл прервется,
следовательно функция вернет 3. `return len_`